# Checkbox always returns one value

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

i've got annoying problem with my checkbox.

Im getting name and value to checkbox from base (NAME:VALUE,NAME2:VALUE2,NAME3:VALUE3, etc). And I made code:

```
$count = count( $matches[0] );    
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
$name_form = $matches[1][$i];
$form= '<tr><td class="head">Name</td><td>';
$value1 = explode(",",$values1); 
$n = count($value);
for ($y=0;$y<$n; $y++) 
{
$value2 = explode(":",$value1 [$y]); 
$form.= '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$name_form.'" value="'.$value2 [1].'"'.$selected.'>'.$value2 [0].'<br />';
}
$form.= '</td></tr>';
}
```

and I can't get values from this checkbox in array's. Everytime the script gives me just one, last checked value. I tried also `foreach($_POST[$name_form]) as $name_form`, it's just not working.

Everyone know what I can do?

Comment: take the space out between `$value2` and `[1]` to start with - and other instances of the same

Comment: I know, It's just simple code for users...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding '[]' at the end of the input's name:

```
$form.= '<input type="checkbox" name="input_name[]" value="'.$value2 [1].'"'.$selected.'>'.$value2 [0].'<br />';
```

Then access the checked values via

```
$checked = $_POST['input_name[]'];
```

Comment: OMG, of course.. I was fighting with this for 1 hour, my mistake. Sorry.